# Error: invalid variable initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have to call a function only if ajax call `success`.

#### Code:

```
<script>
    function removeFromCart(id) {
        var value = "";
        for(var i=0; i<id.length; i++)
            if(!isNaN(id[i]))
                value += id[i];
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://url.com/removefromcart.php",
            data: "id="+value,
            success: function(response){
                afterRemove(response);
            }
        });
    }

    function afterRemove(response) {
        if(response[0] == "r") {
            var prezzo = "";
            for(var i = 1; i<respose.length; i++)
                var prezzo += response[i];
            document.getElementByid("prezzo").innerHTML = prezzo+".00 &euro;";
            $("#segnale"+value).fadeOut();
        }
    }
</script>
```

The problem is that Firebug gives me this error on page load:

```
invalid variable initialization: var prezzo += response[i];
```

This because the `afterRemove` function is called on page load and not only if ajax success. How can fix this?

Comment: You wrote `respose` instead of `response` in your `for` initialization.

Comment: Just FYI, be consistent; don't mix jQuery (`$("#segnale"+value)`) lookups and non-jQuery lookups (`document.getElementByid("prezzo")`).  `$("#prezzo").html(prezzo+".00 &euro;");`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you define/var the variable `prezzo` twice

```
var prezzo = ""; // <-- here
for(var i = 1; i<respose.length; i++)
    var prezzo += response[i]; // <-- and here
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var prezzo += response[i]
```

This is invalid because `var prezzo` means you are creating a new variable named `prezzo`.  You are then trying to add to that variable.  You can't add to a variable that is brand new because it doesn't have a value yet.  Just drop the `var`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var prezzo += response[i];
```

This line makes no sense.  `a += b` means `a = a+b`.

In your case, you're doing `var prezzo += response[i];` which is `var prezzo = prezzo + response[i];`.  `prezzo` doesn't exist yet (because you are declaring it right there), so you can't add to its value, because it doesn't have a value (yet).

(Also, it's invalid syntax)

EDIT: I noticed you declared `var prezzo = "";` earlier, so just remove the `var`:

```
prezzo += response[i];
```

It should look like:

```
var prezzo = "";
   for(var i = 1; i<response.length; i++)
      prezzo += response[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

if you initialize the variable when you do ++. you will always get error...

```
function afterRemove(response) {
    if(response[0] == "r") {
        var prezzo = "";
        for(var i = 1; i<respose.length; i++)
             prezzo += response[i];
        document.getElementByid("prezzo").innerHTML = prezzo+".00 &euro;";
        $("#segnale"+value).fadeOut();
    }
}
```